# AWS S3 Object search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have created an S3 bucket and uploaded about 50,000 objects in the bucket, which are PDF files. The PDFs are saved as the customer's first name, last name, and zip code (for example, John Smith 90005. pdf). My issue is that s3 objects can be searched by prefixes only. For example, you can search for John smith by typing John (first name) and hitting enter, which brings up all customers with the first name John. If a customer's last name is John, He will not appear in the search. You can't search for john smith by typing only smith (Last name) or Zip code since the search is prefix only. How can I search for a customer with the last name or zip code? I can't use AWS Athena since my files are in PDF. Any suggesting?

I tried using AWS Athena to query S3 but didn't work.

Comment: If you want a search engine, deploy and populate a search engine.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to use the Amazon S3 management console to 'search' for objects by a **partial name match**.

The API call to Amazon S3 that lists the objects only returns a maximum of 1000 objects. Thus, listing objects in large buckets can be quite slow, and the API calls do not support 'search' (only Prefix, as you mention).

If you wish to 'search' for objects in an S3 bucket, it is better to **maintain your own index/database** of the objects.

You can also activate [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. You can then use this information in a program to locate objects.